# How to mutably reference one of several things at a time in Rust?

Tags: rust, interior-mutability

Say I want a `train` that can switch between one of 2 tracks at any time and write a `u8` at its current position. Naively something like this:

```rust
struct Train<'a> {
  track_a: &'a mut [u8],
  track_b: &'a mut [u8],
  current_track: &'a mut [u8], // either track_a or track_b
  idx: usize,
}

impl<'a> Train<'a> {
  pub fn new(track_a: &'a mut [u8], track_b: &'a mut [u8]) -> Self {
    Self {
     track_a,
     track_b,
     idx: 0,
     current_track: track_a,
    }
  }

  pub fn toggle_track(&mut self) {
    if self.current_track == self.track_a {
      self.current_track = self.track_b;
    } else {
      self.current_track = self.track_a;
    }
  }

  pub fn write(&mut self, byte: u8) {
    // must be fast - can't waste time choosing track here
    self.current_track[self.idx] = byte;
    self.idx += 1;
  }
}
```

Importantly, we can't waste time deciding which track we're currently on in `write`. Of course, the above code doesn't compile because we mutably borrow `track_a` and `track_b` multiple times.

How might I get something like this to work in Rust? I tried using `RefCell`s for `track_a` and `track_b`, but realized even that doesn't make sense since even immutable `Ref`s would give mutable access to the underlying bytes.

Is unsafe Rust the only way to implement this data structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this without interior mutability, without `unsafe`, and without even a separate `current_track` field if you do it this way:

```
struct Train<'a> {
    track_a: &'a mut [u8], // a.k.a, the current track
    track_b: &'a mut [u8],
    idx: usize,
}

impl<'a> Train<'a> {
    pub fn new(track_a: &'a mut [u8], track_b: &'a mut [u8]) -> Self {
        Self {
            track_a,
            track_b,
            idx: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn toggle_track(&mut self) {
        std::mem::swap(&mut self.track_a, &mut self.track_b);
    }

    pub fn write(&mut self, byte: u8) {
        // must be fast - can't waste time choosing track here
        self.track_a[self.idx] = byte;
        self.idx += 1;
    }
}
```

The trick here of course is to use `std::mem::swap` to do the toggling by swapping the two tracks (one of which we consider the "current" track). The only downside of this would be if you needed to know which one was the "first" and "second" ones given initially (since that may get lost in the toggling), but that can be done via a separate boolean while still leaving `write` branchless.

Answer (score 2):

> How to mutably reference one of several things at a time in Rust?

In short, you can't simply. Not doing this is the core "golden rule" that Rust's safety guarantees are built from.

> we can't waste time deciding which track we're currently on in `write`.

Why not? A simple boolean check is going to be by far the fastest way of making this work: much faster than any sort of interior mutability with (for example) `RefCell`. I would advise you do exactly this. If your real-world example has more than two options, then presumably they're held in some container (like a `Vec`) and you can instead store the index/key/whatever of the chosen object.

Rust's golden rule is: you either have a **single** way to refer to some object (with mutability) or you can have no mutability and aliased references to it. You can never have both.

In principle, you could use raw pointers to do what you're asking for more directly. However, every dereference would be `unsafe` and you'd have to check you're upholding guarantees during those unsafe blocks. A single boolean check seems like a very cheap cost to have the compiler guarantee that safety for you.

Note, that if you do go the `unsafe` route, you're still not allowed to violate the golden rule. That is, you're not allowed to create two `&mut`s that overlap in the memory they refer to. The only difference is that the compiler won't (can't) check if this is the case in an `unsafe` block, but it will still assume that *you* are guaranteeing that it will never happen.

Comment: The boolean check is far too slow - this code needs to run in an extremely hot loop. My vague idea with RefCells was to put manage them in `toggle_track` and somehow get a simple mutable reference to the underlying data for `write`. I don't think this works either, but at least it would be fast.

Comment: @mwlon I highly highly doubt that is the case. Do you have benchmarks that prove this? What kind of usecase doesn't have the overhead available for a single branch instruction?

Comment: Also, the golden rule is that you can't have multiple mutable references to the same thing at the same time. What I want is a single mutable reference to one of two things, which doesn't seem contradictory to the golden rule.

Comment: @mwlon You already have `track_{a,b}: &mut [u8]`. That's your first and only way to refer to each track if it's mutable.

Comment: Q: What kind of usecase doesn't have the overhead available for a single branch instruction?
A: Many, but in this case a compression/decompression loop that can `write` about once every 2 cycles. The above code is of course a toy example.

Comment: @mwlon Can I suggest you write a new question with the real problem then? I've answered the question in your title (you can't) and given you the appropriate warning about trying to get around the compiler checks with `unsafe` (please don't unless you know what you're doing). There might be several ways to help with the real problem (e.g., writing one byte at a time strikes me as particularly inefficient; or you could use a front-/back-buffer approach and swap `&mut T`s), but it's difficult to be helpful through the barrier of a toy example.

Comment: @mwlon Also, you still should just start with the easy, safe, and idiomatic thing and refactor only if profiling shows you it's too slow. Unless you're doing real-time safety-critical embedded work you can **definitely** sacrifice a few cycles in the name of correctness and simplicity. Try not to prematurely optimise: the best optimisations are algorithmic ones, not micro-optimisations.

Comment: @mwlon Last piece of advice against micro-optimising before writing functional code: don't underestimate the compiler's ability to optimise for you. Whether you're interleaving toggles or not, the compiler will have a very good chance of removing almost every check after inlining.

Comment: @JMAA *"Can I suggest you write a new question"* - that seems inappropriate since OP did mention in the question (no edits even) that a check in `.write` would be unacceptable (titles can't convey all the nuances of a post, that's why they're much shorter).

Comment: @kmdreko My point is that the question as written doesn't have enough information to be helpful to the real problem because it's just a proxy. OP stated they didn't want `write` to be any more instructions, but we can't see *why* OP thinks this is the case. Different tweak to the algorithm (e.g., as stated above, where `write` isn't called per-byte) is likely to be a better solution, but we can't tell for sure from a proxy problem. OP has posed a micro-optimisation question and I'd advising them against that because it's almost certainly not a good solution to the real problem.